# Zabbix 5 lack of individual charts.php page - how to restore?

Tags: zabbix, graph

As I can see Zabbix 5.x have no charts.php page so no way to get individual graph displayed without loading all graphs for the host.

I tried to copy charts.php from 4.4.10 to 5.0 - no luck, it won't work and says "Class  not found for action charts.php".

May there be any way of porting this functionality to Zabbix 5.x?

Comment: Try adding a line `'charts.php' => ['CLegacyAction', null, null],` to file `include/classes/mvc/CRouter.php` under "legacy actions".

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft, I did what you've told but no luck, now as I go to charts.php page it says "Class not found for action".